# Android webview app and Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-webview

I have a simple native Android app that is a webview of a website, effectively to make the mobile-ready site native-like if you will. The website already has Google Analytics installed.

What might be a good way to track which visitors are using the app?

- I could adding [Android Native App Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/), but I presume that would
  double track the users. Unless it's smart enough to connect the visits?
- I could pass custom get variable to the site that maybe adds a [custom
  attribute](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) to the tracking for native app users. But that doesn't
  sound very clean.

What might be best for tracking? I feel there's got to be an obvious answer I'm missing.

Comment: hi, if you are using webview to see a website which already has tracking enabled, then will not the mobile report under audience tab be enough for your purpose? or are your looking for some additional data?

Comment: In the analytics I'm looking to be able to distiguish between android webview app vs. mobile web browsers users.

Comment: Did you find any clean solution to your issue?

Answer (score 2):

that should help you:

> Now getting back to the Analytics tracking of this web app, I used the code provided by Google here.
>      So the code becomes somewhat like this.

```
public class  myWebApp  extends Activity{

      Webview mWebview;
      GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();

        // Start the tracker in manual dispatch mode. The following UA-xxxxxxx-x code must be replaced by //your web property ID.

       tracker.startNewSession("UA-xxxxxxx-x", this);

       mWebview = new WebView(this);
       mWebview .setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
       mWebview .loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); 




    private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {

        //After the user visits a particular page, send the tracking notification to GoogleAnalytics.
         @Override
         public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
         {
tracker.trackPageView( mWebview.getUrl());
tracker.dispatch();
         }
      }

   }
```

http://www.the4thdimension.net/2011/11/using-google-analytics-with-html5-or.html

And in stats of google analytics you should get some info at least about operating system android.

Comment: I'm using the same set-up as Sir.Nathan Stassen with google analytics implmented on the actual webapge. I get stats from my app users like they're using defalt browser and a mobile operating system. that's good. But I miss the demographics data a user would report from their standardbrowser. Age/Gender and interests. Would your solution solve this?

Comment: To enable Remarketing, Demographics & Interests reports  you should firstly enable Advertising Features see :   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#tracking-methods