# Integrate a browser into an android app

Tags: android, facebook, browser, android-webview

I am developing an app that latest news from different online pages, magazines etc. In the app I only display the title, source and short description and when a news is clicked it opens on a browser to read the content.

What I want to do is to embed a kind of browser in the app , and when a news is clicked to be open inside the app. For example the links on Facebook app are opened inside the app.

I know how to use a `WebView`, and how to load a link in a `WebView, but I don't know if this is the right way.

Is there a library or some other way in order to provide the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web view control is generally used to open any URL within your application. Therefore you don't have to move to the other application like inbuilt browser, or chrome etc.

As [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) says :

If you want to deliver a web application (or just a web page) as a part of a client application, you can do it using WebView.

Comment: Yes ,that is true, but are all the features that a web page can use in a browser, available in the Web View class?

Comment: Well webview is based on the Chromium open source project.; it is based on the same code as Chrome for Android version 30.  I think you can do your job using it.

Comment: Well it seems, that it handles the things pretty well, once I enabled JavaScript. One last question: If a site has implemented Google Analytic, does it keep track in the same manner when I open it through a `WebView` as when I open it from the browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988618/android-webview-app-and-google-analytics    ; check out this post , it will help you.